# Scroll lock for body while mobile menu is open is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have found several other solutions that demonstrate how you can lock scroll behaviour for a website by using CSS overflow property. As such I have implemented this solution and added the `overflow: hidden;` to the body tag when the menu is open. However when using iOS Safari or Chrome the body is still scrollable.

CSS:

```
    body.opened-drawer {
      overflow: hidden !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
      position: fixed !important;
      z-index: 0 !important;
    }
```

JS:

```
timber.openDrawerMenu = function () {
  var $mobileMenu = $('.nav-bar'),
      $mobileMenuButton = $('#menu-opener'),
      $body = $('body');
      $mobileMenuButton.addClass('opened');
      $mobileMenu.addClass('opened');
      $body.addClass('opened-drawer');

  // Make drawer a11y accessible
  timber.cache.$navBar.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');

  // Set focus on drawer
  timber.trapFocus({
     $container: timber.cache.$navBar,
     namespace: 'drawer_focus'
  });

  // Escape key closes menu
  timber.cache.$html.on('keyup.drawerMenu', function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
      timber.closeDrawerMenu();
    }
  });
}

timber.closeDrawerMenu = function () {

  var $mobileMenu = $('.nav-bar'),
      $mobileMenuButton = $('#menu-opener'),
      $body = $('body');

  $mobileMenuButton.removeClass('opened');
  $mobileMenu.removeClass('opened');
  $body.removeClass('opened-drawer');

  // Make drawer a11y unaccessible
  timber.cache.$navBar.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');

  // Remove focus on drawer
  timber.removeTrapFocus({
    $container: timber.cache.$navBar,
    namespace: 'drawer_focus'
  });

  timber.cache.$html.off('keyup.drawerMenu');
}
```

Comment: What is the menu in question?

Comment: @Kramb mobile menu when expanded (press "menu")

Comment: I just tried it on chrome and its working fine

Comment: @Chiller Chrome on a mobile device or on inspect on desktop? I see it works when inspecting on my desktop in mobile configuration but doesn't actually lock on any of my mobile devices.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">` <-- Try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came to is more of a hack and less a solution but gets the job done either way. What I did was fix the position on the body when the menu was opened and calculate and set the scrollTop position as the menu was opened or closed.

jQuery:

```
    var tempScrollTop = null;

    tempScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    $(window).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);

    var fixed = document.getElementById('fixed--nav');
       fixed.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go for the quick fix

```
body.opened-drawer {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Please find the modified script here

```
function menuDrawerButtons (){

    cache.$mobileMenuButton.on('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('opened')) {
            timber.closeDrawerMenu()
        } else {
            timber.openDrawerMenu();
        }           
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        cache.$mobileMenu.addClass('animate');
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This does solve the issue with the body scrolling, however it causes the page to jump to the top each time the menu is opened. Unfortunately I am also not looking for this behaviour, perhaps you know how to fix this as well?

Comment: you need to add 'event.preventDefault()' (javascript) on the mobile menu button click event

Comment: Just as you wrote it? "event.preventDefault()"

Comment: can you please post your javascript code here, then i can give the exact one.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve the issue. I will leave the code for now if you want to take a look and see how it is affecting the page jump behaviour. Located near the bottom of theme.js

Comment: The login for the website should work fine. I am using now as well.

Comment: page is not jumping... can you apply 'height:100%' in 'body.opened-drawer' class

Comment: I removed the solution you suggested while continuing to work on it. Should I put it back in order for you to test?

Comment: Does the modified script you suggested replace the openDrawerMenu() and closeDrawerMenu() scripts I included above? Or should I just add your script in as well?

Comment: I have added the solution you proposed, and it does in fact stop the page from scrolling, however the page jumps to the top each time the menu is opened. I will leave the code as is for now if you would like to have a look at it.

Comment: @S.Miller You're right, everything works fine except the page jump is really annoying